# unable to resolve the flock error encountered when executing

Tags: perl

encountered below error when executing the automated unit testing in cpp that invoked the perl interpreter and calls the perl subroutine
this is the code snippet :-

```
sub perlflock {
my $xsptr = shift;
my $self = shift;
my ($file, $use_locking) = @_;
logcroak "not a reference" unless ref($self);
logcroak "wrong argument number" unless @_ == 2;    # No @foo in arglist
local *FILE;
if ($use_locking) {
    open(FILE, ">>", $file) || logcroak "can't write into $file: $!";
    unless (1) {
        logcarp
          "Storable::lock_store: fcntl/flock emulation broken on $^O";
        return undef;
    }
    flock(FILE, LOCK_SH | LOCK_NB) ||
      logcroak "can't get exclusive lock on $file: $!";
    truncate FILE, 0;
    # Unlocking will happen when FILE is closed
} else {
    open(FILE, ">", $file) || logcroak "can't create $file: $!";
}
```

frl-plugin:perlscript: ERROR: 'flock' trapped by operation mask at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Storable.pm line 271.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Const/Fast.pm line 15.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: The compilation error appears to be somewhere in `Storable`, and has nothing to do with the C code.

Comment: The operation mask is set in certain restricted environments where the perl interpreter is limited in which opcodes it is allowed to execute - usually for security purposes in less trusted code. In this case the op which executes flock hasn't been listed as trusted.

Comment: @DaveMitchell is there any solution for this issue ?is it required to install flock

Comment: No, something is executing that snippet of perl code within a Safe compartment. So somewhere, you need to let that Safe compartment know that flock is a permitted op. The code snippet you've shown is looks to be exactly the same as the function _store() in Storable.pm, except that it's been renamed to perlflock().

Comment: ... but you haven't shown us how that code is getting called, so I can't make any suggestions on how to fix it. Perhaps first explain where that code snippet you've shown us came from.

Comment: The code snippet is from Storable.pm which invoked from Fast.pm file when compiling, but both the files are not using safe compartment library,
Actually trying to add .pl files from CPP unit testing into a new folder and while adding this new file it invokes few call back functions which is when it failing with this flock error

Answer (score 0):

This error is the result of using `flock` from inside a [Safe](https://metacpan.org/pod/Safe) compartment for which the `flock` operator hasn't been added as permitted operation.